# Get data from other events on the timeline in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to do a scheduler where I can drag and drop events from a table in fullcalendar. I have some restriction, for example a type A event can't go 2 hours or less after a type B event.

So I assume that i need to get the information of the "before and after" events on the schedule point that I'm trying to drop the event, but i have no idea how to do that.

Is there a way to get a list with that data? Is there a way to get the cell where we are attepmting to drop the event?

Thank you!

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents will get you all events currently visible on the calendar. So you can look through those (or filter them via the provided callback mechanism) and decide if any of them are near your proposed drop zone. If you're dropping events from outside the calendar, the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/drop event occurs whenever you drop something onto the calendar area, and the date you're dropping on is available there.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson :) do you know if it's possible to dinamically reubicate events when dropping one event between two events and not overlapping them? Something like the [link](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) dragula plugin

Comment: "reubicate" isn't a word in English I don't think. Did you mean something else? I'm not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @ADyson, oops, I meant relocate

Comment: Sure you could, but you'd have to write all the code for it yourself, to detect nearby events which overlap, and then update their start and end times.

Comment: @ADyson but if I can only get the information of the visible events, how can I work with the following day's events? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, technically getEvents will return all events stored in fullCalendar's memory currently, even if they're not on display right now (sorry, I mis-worded that slightly, the documentation page is clearer), so you _could_ make it so that your event source always returns events for a slightly longer time period than was actually requested by fullCalendar (I assume you're maybe using a JSON event source or custom event feed which accepts start and end parameters, which is the recommended approach). That way you should always have coverage of a few days either side of the current viewing window.